# Python Converting string into a list ignoring the special characters

Tags: python, string, list

I am having a string as :-

```
'Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t12:36 AM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tMostly clear'
```

I want to convert it into a list as :-

```
['Current Weather','12:36 AM','22°','C','RealFeel®','20°','Mostly clear']
```

Is there any python module or function with which I can do so?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

s = 'Current Weather\n\t\n.....t\tMostly clear'
re.split(r'[\n\t]+', s)
```

#### Output:

```
['Current Weather', '12:36 AM', '22°', 'C', 'RealFeel®', '20°', 'Mostly clear']
```

Comment: Why the above code shows different output in REPL mode and print() statement?
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `>>> x` always outputs `repr(x)`. `>>> print(x)` outputs `str(x)`. The actual data structure is always a list of strings. Don't get confused by it's different representations

Comment: (Not in REPL Mode)But when I am trying to print the 2nd element of the list it is showing index out of range

Comment: `x = re.split(r'[\n\t]+', s); print(x[2])` outputs `22°` in my console

Comment: My Code
`crntwthrrprt = repr(datas[0]) #repr(datas[0]) conatins the required string which is copied to crntwthrrprt
Current_Weather_Report = re.split(r'[\n\t]+', crntwthrrprt)
print(Current_Weather_Report[2])
`
**OUTPUT**
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraping.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(Current_Weather_Report[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: `crntwthrrprt = repr(datas[0])` makes little sense. Without knowing the content of `datas`, how can we help. I can only provide solutions for what is shown in the question

Answer (score 2):

Why is everybody using `re`? This library is *very* slow.You can just use `str.split`,if you use it with arguments,you will have to do the `str.isspace` by hand,but it's still pretty fast,this is the code:

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in s.split('\n\t') if not i.isspace()]
['Current Weather', '12:36 AM', '22°', 'C', 'RealFeel®', '20°', 'Mostly clear']
```

Benchmarks:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(r"re.split(r'[\n\t]+', s)",r"""
import re
s = 'Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t12:36 AM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tMostly clear'
""")
2.8587728
timeit.timeit(r"[i.strip() for i in s.split('\n\t') if not i.isspace()]",r"""import re

s = 'Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t12:36 AM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tMostly clear'
""")
1.8853902
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without regex:**

```
[x.strip() for x in st.splitlines() if x.strip()!= '']
```

---

**output:**

```
['Current Weather', '12:36 AM', '22°', 'C', 'RealFeel®', '20°', 'Mostly clear']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python regex. Here is an example:

```
import re
def sentance_to_list(sentence):
ls=re.split(r'["\t|\n"]\s*', sentence)   # split \t or \n
return ls

strr='Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t12:36 AM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tMostly clear'
newstrr=sentance_to_list(strr)
print(newstrr)
```

output:

```
['Current Weather', '12:36 AM', '22°', 'C', 'RealFeel®', '20°', 'Mostly clear']
```

You could read more on re https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html